# User control created under wrap panel is not wrapping content on actual page where i m using it

Tags: controls

I have created a user control having controls in it under a wrap panel, but when i am adding it on run time on other page its wrapping functionality is not working.
I have also tried to take a wrap panel on the page where i want to show the 
user control.***strong text***
[enter image description here][1]

```
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Margin="2,-25,0,0" x:Name="TB4" Width="140" Height="26" FontFamily="{StaticResource inventoryRegularFont}" Text="Auto-Order" Foreground="#414042" FontSize="14" FontWeight="SemiLight" />
                    <CalendarDatePicker  Grid.Column="1" Height="30" Width="220" Margin="-8,-35,0,0" Style="{StaticResource CalendarDatePickerStyleOwn }" FontWeight="Light" FontSize="13" DateFormat = "{}{month.integer}/{day.integer}/{year.full}" Name="DTAutoorder" PlaceholderText="Select Auto-Order Date" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" LostFocus="DTAutoorder_LostFocus" TabIndex="4" />
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" x:FieldModifier="public" Text="" Name="TBAutoOrderError" FontSize="11" Foreground="red" Margin="20,25,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
                </Grid>
            </StackPanel>
```

Comment: Please show your code, what did you try and where did it fail.

Comment: i have added a picture of code pls check that

Comment: In Stack Overflow, you should share code and not screenshots of code. To learn more about how to ask (and Stack Overflow in general), please visit https://stackoverflow.com/tour